# How is this answer not "Not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59534513/1244884).

Nothing wrong with the content but in my opinion it doesn't attempt to answer the question at all and only suggests debugging steps which I think the author has tried already (I may be wrong of course).

I really think this should have been a comment.

Am I wrong? I guess I was but why?

Comment: It is an attempt to answer the question. Suggesting debugging steps does a valid answer make. If you found the answer to be wrong or not useful, then that’s a reason to downvote it. Moderators do not police the accuracy or correctness of answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok that makes sense. Cheers.

Comment: For transparency's sake, I handled this. Cody explained it well. ^